# How to conbine indexing in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb

my pipeline

```
'pipeline' => [
            ['$match' => ['username' => 'xxx']],
            ['$sort' => ['create_at' => 1]],
            ['$limit' => 1]
        ]
```

Create Index to match or sort ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a shell query. `hint` option to force the usage of the specified index.
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/aggregate/

```
db.collection.aggregate([
        {'$match' : {'username' : 'xxx'}},
        {'$sort' : {'create_at' => 1}},
        {'$limit' => 1},
        { hint: { username: 1, create_at: 1 } }
)
```